# Is there way to define the first derivative of a function in Lill's method?

Tags: calculus, geometry

Lill's method is a visual way to find the real roots of a polynomial equation. It involves drawing a straight line with lengths equal to the coefficients of the polynomial. The solution can be found by using a slope of a right triangle.
[Lill's method - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lill%27s_method)

The values of a polynomial function can be "defined" as a distance between the vertice of the last polynomial coefficient and the path that we draw using right angles.
[Polynomial function's value](https://orimath.wordpress.com/2021/08/21/lills-method-origami-and-solving-cubics/)

[**Cubic function with defined function's value**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyAaP.png)

What I want to do is to find the local maximum and minimum in Lill's path. So, I'm curious if I can "define" a line that represents the first derivative of a cubic function and let it equal to zero, or if it can't be done.

What I have done is by using the derivative's definition, and I got that a point (P in the picture) is the derivative of a function which its value is zero. But I think that's not the correct way to do it.

[**My way to do the derivative in cubic function**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCe85.png)

[I drew the function and its derivative with the same "first coefficient"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbpNK.png)

Please correct me if I'm wrong, Thanks.